Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter 2, Exercise 2.13.
Part (a) of Exercise 2.13:

Let $f:X\mapsto Y $ be a continuous map of topological spaces. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$, and $\mathcal{G}$
be a sheaf on $Y$.
(a) Show that there exist canonical morphisms of sheaves
$\mathcal{G}\mapsto f_{*}f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$, $f^{-1}f_{*}\mathcal{F}\mapsto \mathcal{F}$, that if $f$ is a closed immersion, the first morphism is surjective, and that if $f$ is an (open or closed) immersion, the second morphism is an isomorphism.

Establishing the canonical morphisms: for $\mathcal{G}\mapsto f_{*}f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$, I've got:
Let the sheaf defined by
$$U\mapsto \lim_{\underset{f(U) \subseteq V}{\longrightarrow}}\mathcal{G}(V)$$
be denoted $f^{-1}\mathcal{G}^{\dagger}$. For open subsets $V_{0},V\subseteq Y$; $g_{V}$ will denote the projection of $\mathcal{G}(V)$ into the above direct limit where $U=f^{-1}(V_{0})$. The canonical map $\mathcal{G}(V)\mapsto f_{*}f^{-1}\mathcal{G}(V)$ will be defined to be, (for an $s\in \mathcal{G} (V_{0})$, $\theta_{1}: f^{-1}\mathcal{G}^{\dagger} \mapsto f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$):
$$s\mapsto (\theta_{1}(f^{-1}(V_{0}))\circ g_{V_{0}})(s)$$
I'm very stuck in establishing a canonical morphism $f^{-1}f_{*}\mathcal{F}\mapsto \mathcal{F}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $f^{-1}_{pre}f_*\mathcal F$ be the presheaf
$$f^{-1}_{pre}f_*\mathcal F(U)=\lim_{V\supset f(U)}\mathcal F(f^{-1}(V)).$$
Then the sheafification of $f_{pre}^{-1}f_*\mathcal F$ is $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F$ by the definition of the inverse image functor. Thus to give a homomorphism $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F\to \mathcal F$ it suffices to provide a homomorphism $f^{-1}_{pre}f_*\mathcal F\to \mathcal F$ and sheafifiy.
To give a homomorphism $f^{-1}_{pre}f_*\mathcal F\to \mathcal F$, you need to give, for every open subset $U$ of $X$, a homomorphism
$$f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F(U)=\lim_{V\supset f(U)}\mathcal F(f^{-1}(V))\to \mathcal F(U).$$
In other words, for we need to give, for every open subset $V\supset f(U)$ of $Y$, a compatible family of homomorphisms $\mathcal F(f^{-1}(V))\to\mathcal F(U)$. But since $V\supset f(U)$ is equivalent to $f^{-1}(V)\supset U$, there is an obvious choice of such a homomorphism: the restriction.

Forgot about the universal property of the associated sheaf. Greatly appreciated. ❤️.
